# Finding number of HH:MM between two different dates in SQL

Tags: sql-server, date, difference

I am creating a turnaround time report in SQL for my job and need to be able to calculate the number of HH:MM between two different dates taking into account the DAYS as well as the HOURS. I seem to find a lot of answers that will bring back just the HOURS but need the DAYS as well.

EX: Difference in HH:MM between '2017-04-18 16:03:00.000' and '2017-04-19 20:59:00.000'

CURRENTLY attempting

`CONVERT (CHAR(5),turn.[ADMIN DTTM]-turn.[VERIFY DTTM], 108) as 'VERIFIED to ADMINISTERED'`

This is returning HH:MM but only for the "00:00:00:00" indicated: 04:56

But what I need it to be returning is the combination of days and time: **28:56** OR **01:04:56**

Thanks

Comment: Is it SQL Server database?

Comment: I am quite new to SQL so unsure of the proper answer to that.  I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT FORMAT([Minutes] / 1440, '#') + ':' 
  + FORMAT(([Minutes] % 1440) / 60, '00') + ':' 
  + FORMAT([Minutes] % 60, '00') AS [Result]
FROM
(
  SELECT DATEDIFF(mi, turn.[ADMIN DTTM], turn.[VERIFY DTTM]) AS [Minutes]
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT '2017-04-18 16:03:00.000' AS [ADMIN DTTM], '2017-04-19 20:59:00.000' AS [VERIFY DTTM]
  ) turn
) t
```

You will need to replace

> (SELECT '2017-04-18 16:03:00.000' AS [ADMIN DTTM], '2017-04-19 20:59:00.000' AS [VERIFY DTTM])

with your table.

Comment: I apologize in advance for my newness to the world of SQL.  When you state @differenceInMinutes am I replacing that with a column name or is that going to become the new column name?  ALSO instead of typing out actual dates, if I have a column 'turn.[ORDER DTTM]' that is bringing back a list of them can I put the column name in place of the date?  Thank you for your patience and assistance!

Comment: Please edit the question and mention what result you want to see.

Comment: I have updated my original question to provide what I am getting with my query and what I am needing it to give me

Answer (score 0):

You were taking the right approach by subtracting one value from the other.  The trick is to use the FORMAT function to specify that you want the result in days, hours and minutes.

```
SELECT FORMAT(turn.[VERIFY DTTM]-turn.[ORDER DTTM] - 1,'dd:HH:mm') as 'ORDERED to VERIFIED'
```

To understand why you need the "- 1" you need to understand what type of result you're getting back.  If you just have:

```
SELECT turn.[VERIFY DTTM]-turn.[ORDER DTTM]
```

you'll see that the difference is returned as a datetime commencing from '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'.  Exactly one day's difference will give a result of '1900-01-0**2** 00:00:00.000'.  Internally datetime values are stored with the days as whole numbers and the time as decimals, so by subtracting one (day) you get the result you are after.

Two caveats though:

1. This will only work if the number of days difference is less than or equal to 31 (i.e. the number of days in January).
2. As presented above this will only work if there is at *least* one day's difference such as in your example.

If you want to cater for the possibility of less than a day's difference you can conditionally modify the FORMAT string accordingly.

```
SELECT FORMAT(turn.[VERIFY DTTM]-turn.[ORDER DTTM] - 1,IIF(turn.[VERIFY DTTM]-turn.[ORDER DTTM] < 1,'00','dd') + ':HH:mm') as 'ORDERED to VERIFIED'
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... unfortunately it is actual giving me the exact same result I was getting before.  I have updated my Question to provide a better understanding of what I am needing

Comment: @downeys1725 - I've updated my answer to align with your rephrased question.